# Bash script to read line and increment

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file that has the following format

```
1|3
7|10 
11|16
```

and I would like with a script to have the following format

```
1
2
3
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
```

Basically I have a range and in the first column is the start number and in the second column the end number and I would liked to have the output file with all the numbers from that range in a new line .

Comment: There seems to be several questions here: Which bit are you stuck on?

Comment: I don't even have any kind of idea on how to start .

Comment: Can you read a file? Can you read it line by line? Can you read the individual fields? Can you construct a range from two numbers? Just do one of these. When it is working, add another, until done. How do you climb a tall building? One step at a time. If you try to jump, then you will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F'|' '{for (i = $1; i <= $2; i++) print i}' < input > output
```

Comment: This might be a tiny bit faster: `{for (i=$1; i<=$2; i++) print i}` as it doesn't have to rebuild $0 for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @glennjackman. Thanks. You could argue that the NF, $0 don't need to be updated unless they are accessed, but in my tests with mawk and the _one true awk_, using the `for` loop is faster indeed, so I'm going to follow your recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

```
tr -s \| " " < file.txt |xargs -l1 seq > output.txt
```

Comment: Why the files?, stdin and stdout are more flexible.

Comment: In the question there was an input file and output also.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the values are strictly valid base 10 numbers (if not, clean them):

```
$ cat ./script.sh
#!/bin/bash
while   IFS='|' read a b
do      until   ((a>b))
        do      printf '%d\n' "$((a++))"
        done
done

$ ./script <infile >outfile
```